# Report in Salesforce for Records where my name is in a custom user lookup field

Tags: reporting

i have a 2 User lookup fields on the Case Object. 
One is the Standard Owner field and the other is a custom lookup field to Users.

In the Reportbuilder you can choose "my cases".
And what i want is to build one report with the criteria show me all cases where my name is in the custom lookup field.
I dont want to build for every User one single Report.

Is there a smarter way to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

BR
Tarek

Answer (score 3):

Follow Steve Molis' answer here ( https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gp92AAA )

To reiterate for completeness:

Create a custom formula field on the object.
Datatype:  Formula(Number,0)
Formula:  IF(Custom_Lookup_Field__c = $User.Id , 1 , 0)

Then, in your report just filter on that new formula field.

Do note, you'll have to send him one of these:

[image: A Beer]

Comment: sounds like a good solution but did this work when i have that report as a component in a dashboard?

Comment: good name for the formula field would be `is Case referenced to running user?`